# typings has wrong referenced path

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I have a small little Typescript library that I am trying to publish to npmjs with the correct typings. However, it seems like it's not exporting the types file properly.

I have a simple method in the `src/index.ts` file and typings from `src/typings/index.d.ts`. (some function names/parameters renamed)

```
import { CoolData } from "./typings";
export const sampleExport = async (): Promise<CoolData[]> => {}
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "declarationDir": "dist",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "dist"]
}
```

and partial `package.json`

```
"main": "dist/index",
"types": "src/typings/index.d.ts",
"files": [
    "dist",
    "src/typings/index.d.ts"
],
```

When the `index.d.ts` is generated inside the `dist` folder, it has the wrong referenced path to the typings.

```
import { CoolData } from "./typings";
// Cannot find module './typings' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Even though that's the case, I can still publish and use the library. However, the downside that it's returning an `any` type for the method.

```
await sampleExport([]); // return type Promise<any>
```

Been trying to fix this for quite some time but to no avail. Hope that someone could help me out. Thank you.

Edit:

If I were to allow Typescript to auto generate my typings, it would generate this in `dist/index.d.ts` with the error

```
import { CoolData } from "./typings";
// Cannot find module './typings' or its corresponding type declarations.
export declare const sampleExport: () => Promise<CoolData[]>;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map
```

Comment: Try changing the `types` field of the package.json file to reference the "dist" folder. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package) explicitly say to "Set the types property to point to your bundled declaration file." - since the bundle is in the "dist" directory, types should point to it.

Comment: @OlegValterI have edited my response! Please do take a look. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand your update? Did you switch the `types` field to point to the "dist" folder? Can you show how your output folder structure looks like?

Comment: @OlegValterjust 3 files. `dist/index.js`, `dist/index.d.ts` and `dist/index.d.ts.map`. And `dist/index.d.ts` would have the error as described in the edits above.

Comment: I see you figured that out for yourself. Just noticed that you use a `*.d.ts` file as a source file, which I wouldn't do as your codebase is in typescript - you should rely on `*.d.ts` file emission *from* TS files. You could change the declaration file to a real `*.ts` and have the unnecessary emitted .js file removed as part of the build step. That said, up to this day I am unsure how to deal with purely ambient .ts files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to export a function declaration in `src/typings/index.d.ts`

```
export declare function sampleExport(): Promise<CoolData[]>;
```

and remove the `declaration` and `declarationMap` in `tsconfig.json`